Can i use the old and new values from the watcher in the mounted cycle?
I need to use this.prev and this.curr in the mounted cycle, with the updated changes from the watcher. How can I access these up to date values in the mounted cycle?
 <template>
  <component
    :is="'nuxt-link'"
    :to="{ path: slug, query: { scroll: 'false' } }"
    :class="linkClasses"
    v-on:click.native="getSelectedFacet($event.target.textContent)"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["filterVariantState"],

  props: {
    facetKey: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    facet: {
      type: String | undefined,
      required: true,
    },

    selectedFacets: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    selectedFacet: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },

    results: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return [];
      },
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      trackFacets: [],
      showAnimation: false,
      updatedFacet: null,
      updatedFacetKey: null,
      prev: {
        attributes: [],
        name: "",
      },
      curr: {
        attributes: [],
        name: "",
      },
    };
  },

  computed: {
    // Get data object from store
    dataObj() {
      return this.$store.getters["page/data"];
    },

    // Get Previous and Current Facets from store
    storedFacets() {
      return this.$store.getters["page/facets"];
    },

    // Get Selected Facets
    storedSelectedFacet() {
      return this.$store.getters["page/selectedFacet"];
    },

    facets() {
      let currentFacet = {};
      currentFacet[this.facetKey] = this.facet;

      return Object.assign({}, this.selectedFacets, currentFacet);
    },

    // Check if product is availble
    productIsAvailable() {
      return this.productAvailability ? true : false;
    },

    // Computes the slug of each facet
    slug() {
      let result;

      if (!this.filterVariantState.clearAll && this.results.length > 2) {
        result = this.results.find((x) => {
          return Object.keys(this.facets).every((facet) => {
            return (x[facet] ? x[facet].raw : null) === this.facets[facet];
          });
        });
      }

      let productSlug = result ? result.slug.raw : "";

      if (productSlug === "") {
        result = this.results.find(
          (x) =>
            x[this.facetKey] &&
            x[this.facetKey].raw === this.facets[this.facetKey]
        );
      }

      return result ? result.slug.raw : "";
    },

    // Computes product availability
    productAvailability() {
      let result =
        !this.filterVariantState.clearAll && this.results.length > 2
          ? this.results.find((x) => {
              return Object.keys(this.facets).every((facet) => {
                return (x[facet] ? x[facet].raw : null) === this.facets[facet];
              });
            })
          : this.results.find(
              (x) =>
                x[this.facetKey] &&
                x[this.facetKey].raw === this.facets[this.facetKey]
            );

 
      return result ? result.slug.raw : "";
    },

    // Current selected variant
    currentVariant() {
      return this.selectedFacet === this.facet;
    },

    // Link Classes
    linkClasses() {
      return {
        "bg-gray-100 text-gray-400": !this.productIsAvailable,
        "text-gray-900": this.productIsAvailable,
        pulse: this.showAnimation && this.currentVariant,
      };
    },

    animationIsTrue() {
      return showAnimation ? true : false;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    // Get facetKey from value // Adjust styling for styling detector for storage as it entered into the backend off
    getKeyByValue(object, value) {
      return Object.keys(object).find((key) =>
        key === "storage"
          ? object[key].replaceAll(" ", "") === value
          : object[key] === value
      );
    },

    // This method gets you the facetKey that is NOT changed when you click on a faded option and your selection has been changed
    getUnchangedKey() {
      // Get two arrays of facetKeys
      let result = this.storedFacets.map((value) =>
        value.attributes.map((attribute) =>
          this.getKeyByValue(this.dataObj.attributes, attribute)
        )
      );

      // Need the last two results to continue
      if (result.length === 2) {
        // Remove sim and network from the arrays
        result[0] = result[0].filter(
          (str) => str !== "sim" && str !== "network"
        );
        result[1] = result[1].filter(
          (str) => str !== "sim" && str !== "network"
        );

        let unchangedKey = [];

        // Compare the two arrays, if there is a matching facetKey, it means it has not changed and so we will not fire the text for that facetKey
        for (let i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < result[1].length; j++) {
            if (result[0][i] === result[1][j]) {
              unchangedKey.push(result[0][i]);
            }
          }
        }

        return unchangedKey ? unchangedKey : "";
      }
    },

    // Get selected facet value on click
    getSelectedFacet(value) {
      // Set the value found in the $event click
      this.updatedFacet = value.trim().toLowerCase();

      // Dispatch the getSelectedFacets action and pass through the facet value that has just been selected/clicked
      this.$store.dispatch("page/getSelectedFacet", this.updatedFacet);
    },
  },

  watch: {
    dataObj(newVal, oldVal) {
      // this.fetchFacets();
      this.prev = {
        attributes: Object.values(oldVal.attributes),
        name: this.dataObj.name,
      };
      this.curr = {
        attributes: Object.values(newVal.attributes),
        name: this.dataObj.name,
      };
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    // Conditionally show pulse animation
    let n = 1;
    let queue = [];
    // let namesQueue = [];

    // Loop through both arrays and join them create one array
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      let prevFacets = this.prev.attributes;
      let currFacets = this.curr.attributes;

      // let prevProductName = this.prev.name;
      // let currProductName = this.curr.name;

      console.log("prev", this.prev.attributes);
      console.log("curr", this.curr.attributes);

      // namesQueue.push(prevProductName, currProductName);

      // Loop through prev facets
      for (let j = 0; j < prevFacets.length; j++) {
        queue.push(prevFacets[j]);
      }

      // Loop through current facets
      for (let k = 0; k < currFacets.length; k++) {
        queue.push(currFacets[k]);
      }
    }

    // Loop through joint array and check for no duplicates
    for (let i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < queue.length; j++) {
        if (queue[i] === queue[j]) {
          queue.splice(i, 1); // Remove the element at index i
          queue.splice(j - 1, 1); // Remove the element at index j (adjusted after removing i)
          i--; // Adjust i since the array has been modified
          break; // Restart checking from the new i position
        }
      }
    }

    // The queue removes any duplicates
    // So, if there is only pair of facets left (length === 2), then turn off the animation as only the selected facet has changed
    if (queue.length === 2) {
      this.showAnimation = false;

      // Else if, they are multiple pairs of changes and the product is still the same, then turn on the animation as the facet options have changed, and also, alert the changing text
    } else if (queue.length > 2) {
      this.showAnimation = true;

      // Conditionally show updated label

      // Find key based on the value of the selected facet found in storedSelectedFacets
      this.updatedFacetKey = this.getKeyByValue(
        this.dataObj.attributes,
        this.storedSelectedFacet
      );

      // Pass the facet key to ProductVariantFilter to trigger the "update" label
      this.$emit("updatedFacetOptions", {
        facetKey: this.updatedFacetKey,
        // Get unchanged facetKey, if there is one
        unchangedFacetKey: this.getUnchangedKey(),
      });
    }
  },
};
</script>




I tried putting my mounted content in the watcher, but i only see my animation for a second because it has to be handled in the mounted cycle

I'm not sure about when the watcher is exactly called. Could you try adding await this.$nextTick() at the start of the mounted function?

Its not an async function so I cant add 'await'. But i can add the whole component if that helps?

Doesn't need to specifically be async, you can slap it there so that you're sure that nextTick is done before running anything else.

The whole page fails when I try to add await

You can make the mounted function async. Just use mounted: async () => {...}

I tried this, but it gives me this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$nextTick')'

I ended up dispatching them to the vuex store so they could be stored there and i could use a getters function to retrieve the values I stored and use them in the mounted cycle, with the dynamic data that changes in the watcher function
